# Кнопка "Отменить" iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

На клавиатуре в iPad есть кнопка "Отменить" Она отменяет последние действия. Как ее можно отловить.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)aTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Тут я вижу его как

```
const char * _char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");
//int = -8;
```

А это значение `int = -8`, значение удаления. Мне надо отловить тот символ, или строку, которую хочет вставить кнопка "Отменить"

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать следующий подход

```
//UIKeyboardDidHideNotification после анимации скрытия
//UIKeyboardWillHideNotification до анимации скрытия

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

И метод обработчик нотификации

```
-(void)onKeyboardHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //клава спряталась или щас спрячется 
}
```

Comment: Нажми ответ как принятый